# Azure IAM - Custom Role

Tags: azure, identity-management

Trying to figure out if it is possible to have a custom IAM role where it has contributor to the resources but not the ability to create resources. We need a solution besides automating the IAM roles on a resource, I'd rather just give that role on the resource group and not let the developers be able to create new resources. Maybe I do it with Azure Policy but a role would be better since it's easier to automate.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/azure_custom_role.html) it says,

> By default we use the "Contributor" role that is included into Azure. All subscription resources are ***accessible*** to users with the Contributor role.
> If you wish to limit the Controller access permissions, you can do so by creating a custom role with a set of permissions required by the Controller

Thanks @JohnC according to [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309532/azure-permission-needed-for-creating-resource-group-rbac#:%7E:text=Grant%20the%20owner%20permission%20of,permission%20of%20all%20resource%20group.) it says,

> Azure supports  [custom RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles), you can create a custom role with the Microsoft.Resources  [resource provider operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources).

When you are creating the custom role check whether the below azure permission is not included in that custom role as this permission gives the user the right to create a resource group.
If this permission is not included in the custom role then that user will not be able to create a resource group, hence any azure resource will not  be deployed.

```
Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write
```

***References:***

[Create or update Azure custom roles using the Azure portal - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I'll to go through ALL permissions and exclude them from */write.  They also include create/update inside many of the same permissions. We'll have to figure it out I guess.